# Jquery change opacity on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using bootstrap nav-pills to create a navigation box. Its has two list items. When the user clicks one, I want the other to fade out to show which is selected in a clear way to the user.

What I would also like to do is add a hover function, so that when you hover over the faded out list item, the opacity returns to full.

My Javascript is not the best, here is the code I am using to get the fades,maybe this itself could be improved.

HTML:

```
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="fadeWorker">
        <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab" id="worker">
            <img src="img/worker.png" alt="" />
            <span>I AM A WORKER</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="fadeAgency">
        <a href="#2a" id="agency" data-toggle="tab">
            <img src="img/agency.png" alt="" />
            <span>I AM AN AGENCY</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$( "#worker" ).click(function() {
    $( ".fadeAgency" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.2, function() {
    });
    $( ".fadeWorker" ).fadeTo( "fast" , 1, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});

$( "#agency" ).click(function() {
    $( ".fadeWorker" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.2, function() {
    });
    $( ".fadeAgency" ).fadeTo( "fast" , 1, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with css and the pseudo class `!important`

http://jsfiddle.net/tkmwx3q1/

```
.fadeWorker:hover,
.fadeAgency:hover{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

`!important` is a bad habbit. What it does is it changes any styles, or in other words it is "stronger" than inline styles.

So lets say you have your `CSS` rules which get overwritten by `Javascript inline-style` rules which you can overwrite again with `!important`

IF it still should be fading: http://jsfiddle.net/tkmwx3q1/2/

```
.fadeWorker:hover,
.fadeAgency:hover{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

AND you didn't ask for this but here is an updated JS you might like. It does the same: have a play with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkmwx3q1/1/

```
$( "ul.nav-pills li" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul.nav-pills li" ).not(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.2, function() {});
    $(this).fadeTo( "fast" , 1, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: I had already tried to do this, for some reason even with the important tag it ignores the pseudo class

Comment: @WebblyBrown updated the answer a few times. you might like the changes

Comment: maybe this: `.fade:hover {opacity: 1 !important;}` after line 684 in your style.css

Comment: @WebblyBrown you have to check (debug with firebug) if you add classes with some CSS rules you need to overwrite each single one of them ... (if your code is clean though it will only be at one place)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3 animation like

```js
$(".fader").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('fade');
  $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
});
```

```css
.fader {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.fader.fade {
  opacity: .2;
}
li.fader:hover {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="fader">
    <a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab" id="worker">
      <img src="img/worker.png" alt="" /><span>I AM A WORKER</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="fader">
    <a href="#2a" id="agency" data-toggle="tab">
      <img src="img/agency.png" alt="" /><span>I AM AN AGENCY</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can see thus works on the fiddle but I cant get it to run on my site, notsure why

Comment: @WebblyBrown 1 reason could be there is some other css that is messing up our rules

Comment: @WebblyBrown try to copy other related css rules to the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use "transition", and then put this on "cliked" "notClicked" class. And change the class with javascript.

When you click one change its class to "clicked" and pass the other one to "notClicked"

```css
a:hover {
    transition: all 800ms ease 0s;
    color:rgb(255,88,0);
}
```

```html
<a>my text</a>
```